# Chield gameobject with local postion Vector3.zero, doesn't have same position as parent object

Tags: unity-game-engine, position

I have following code:

```
relationHint = Instantiate(prefabRelationHint) as GameObject;
relationHint.transform.SetParent(imageObject.transform, false);
relationHint.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
```

Goal is to spawn relationHint (white square with text) at same position as imageObject (Red smile face). Everything look OK in inspector, since relationHint gets created as chield of imageObject and has position 0,0,0, but on the camera it doesn't have same position as imageObject.

[image: Position of relationHint]
[image: Position of relationImage]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set HitRelation's pivot to x:0.5, y:0.5. This is the center value.

When you make it (2, 2) you're saying that game objects center is in (2, 2) point. And this point is centered when you set localPosition to (0, 0, 0).

Comment: Thank you, I just discovered my self few minutes ago, that I had probably by mistake changed the pivot somewhere in the past.